# Parameters to operator new

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I am trying to write a custom allocator for a particular class. My experience with allocators is basically none, so this might be obvious.

I wish my allocations to be dependent on certain parameters. Roughly speaking, I wish to have multiple memory managers, each managing a few objects. When creating the objects, I shall know which manager the object should belong to. Having read up a fair bit on overloading `operator new`, I am lost as to how I can implement what I need.

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) says that there is a version of `operator new` that accepts user defined parameters, but it seems this version would not be called while allocating objects using `new`. Could somebody point out how to construct anything other than a global allocator? On a related note, how can I call parameterized constructors if I am using overloaded class-specific `operator new`?

Comment: Do you have to write custom `operator new` overloads? The STL uses allocator classes which can be passed as template arguments, rather than calling `new` directly.

Comment: I need them for custom data structures that don't use STL classes. templatetypedef seems to have the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a customized allocator that takes in extra parameters by defining an overload for `operator new` like this:

```
void* operator new (size_t size, /* extra parameters here */) {
    /* Do something, then return a pointer to at least 'size' bytes. */
}
```

You can then use your allocator by writing

```
MyObject* obj = new (/* extra params */) MyObject(/* constructor args */);
```

For example, here's a silly custom allocator that prints out a message when you allocate something:

```
void* operator new(size_t numBytes, const std::string& message) {
    std::cout << "Custom message: " << message << std::endl;

    /* Use the default allocator to get some bytes. */
    return ::operator new(numBytes);
}
```

You could call it by writing

```
std::complex<double>* obj = new ("Hello, world!") std::complex<double>(0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: I always thought placement new was only for cases where fresh memory was not required. Was I mistaken?

Comment: The code above actually isn't for a placement new. Placement new is a specific overload of `operator new` and the syntax for invoking it looks a lot like the syntax for invoking the above allocator because they're both using the same language feature. You are right, though, that placement new is appropriate for spots where you already have the memory lying around.

Comment: Looking at this, I feel that placement new is just one version of this, where the "extra parameters" is a pointer to a memory location already allocated. Correct?

Comment: @user2308211 : Indeed, and nothrow-new is another example

Comment: @user2308211 "placement new" is used both for the general new-with-argument (the `(stuff)` is a *new-placement* in the grammar) construct, and to refer to the specific reserved forms of placement new that takes a `void*`.