# What arguments does new take?

Tags: c++

Does `new` in C++ call a constructor behind the scenes? Or is it the other way around?

I have seen code like `new MyClass(*this)` which confuses me, since I didn't know that `new` could take arguments.

Maybe that's because `new` can call a constructor and, as a result, it can take the arguments declared by a constructor?

Comment: @appleapple That is **not** placement new

Comment: While this isn't a bad question, it's a sign you need a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). A constructor can take all kinds of arguments. Why would you think otherwise? How else does `std::string` get constructed with a pre-existing value?

Comment: @NathanOliver oh right. it's just a constructor argument

Comment: `new MyClass(*this)` calls the constructor, you are passing the arguments to the constructor, not `new` itself.

Comment: Look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) (2)

Comment: The expression `new MyClass(*this)` does result in a constructor call, assuming the memory for the object was successful. This is not different to the expression `new MyClass`; the latter just uses a constructor that works without specifying any constructor arguments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between `new` and `operator new`.
The `new` operator uses a hidden `operator new` function to allocate memory and then it also "value-initializes" the object by calling its constructor with the parameters after the class name.

In your case you call `new` which allocates memory using `::operator new()` and then it initializes an object of `MyClass` class in that memory using a constructor with the parameter `*this`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        int m_value; 
        A(int value): m_value(value){};
};

int main (){

    int *a  = new int; 

    auto b= new A(1); 

    std::cout << *a << std::endl; 
    std::cout << b->m_value << std::endl; 
    printf("%02x ", *b);

}
```

```
Program returned: 
0
15
0f
```

As you can see, the `new` for the `a` variable creates only a pointer that is value-initialized to 0. That's why when we dereference it we have 0 (all bit all 0, int is 4 bytes most of the time and the pointer point to a memory content = to 0x0000)

But for the `b` variable we pass parameters. And if we look at the memory content of the `b` object we can read `0f` which means it contains 15 (the member value)

Comment: I suspect the OPs confusion comes from awareness that `operator new` can be overridden. It might be worth noting that the `new` operator calls `operator new` and then it calls the constructor on that memory.

Comment: Thanks! @MooingDuck I just updated the code snippet with what I understood you meant. Please let me know if you think that's wrong!

Comment: @Josh: I have reworded the answer to hopefully answer the question without diving *too much* into arcane details of what value-initialization is, or how overriding `operator new` works. Neofelis: I dislike that I made so many changes to your post, but apparently Josh was still confused. I hope the edits are ok.

Comment: For those curious, this offers a little more insight into overriding `operator new`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/897bc134e2cc56f0 It's interesting, but usually pointless, and best to avoid this arcane corner of C++.

Comment: For those curious, this answer offers a little more insight into how to provide parameters to `operator new` itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800940/parameters-to-operator-new. tldr the extra parameters go between `new` and the class name.  `A* p = new("new-parameter") A("A-ctor-parameter");`

Comment: "int is 4 bits most of the time" << no, it's 4 or 8 _bytes_, i.e. 32 or 64 bits most of the time. also, `0x0000` would be 2 bytes / 16 bits (one nibble is 4 bits or half a byte long and you put four nibbles here)

Comment: No worries, your changes were useful. And you managed to keep the answer "simplify" to avoid getting lost in the details. By the way, Josh seemed to have understood because no new good news

Comment: CherryDT, Sorry, the word bytes in my language does not exist and I got everything mixed up.

Answer (score 4):

`MyClass(*this)` creates an object of type `MyClass` by calling its constructor and passing `*this` as an argument. Putting `new` behind it means the object is allocated on the heap instead of the stack. It's not `new` which is taking the argument, it's `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not `new` taking arguments, it's the constructor taking arguments.

Comment: You may need to add a tutorial on the difference between a new-expression and the new operator.